# How to prevent staff users from editing/deleting superuser in django

Tags: django

I want to be able to allow certain staff users the rights to add other users and staff but what seems weird to me is that 1) a staff member can just change their own privileges to superuser or just make a new user and grant superuser privileges to them.  2) delete a superuser or revoke their superuser status

Some staff users should be able to modify/create/delete users but they should not be able to delete super users nor assign permissions to themselves or other users that they do not have the permission themselves.

This has always been logic I have incorporated into my user systems that I've written in PHP and I was just wondering if there was a way to change these settings in Django as I really like Python/Django (I'm just beginning to learn it) and can see myself migrating away from PHP.  But part of the beauty for me lied in the admin panel and if that is something that cannot be changed, that's kind of cringe-worthy.

It reminds me of a restaurant POS system that I used to use when I was a GM.  As the GM, I had powers that shift managers did not have.  However, the shift managers could add a fingerprint to my profile (theirs) and then just log in as me and do anything they wanted to.  I always felt this was a severe security breach and even took disciplinary action on an employee for doing this.  It also allowed the shift managers to create new employees with titles that were above theirs which created the same problem as they could just create a new GM or Area Manager, login, do whatever they wanted, and see all kinds of things that they shouldn't (like their colleagues' salaries), and then hide (not delete) the user.  (this is how he got caught)

If anyone has a fix or any ideas and suggestions, I'd love to hear them and keep learning this exciting new language.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django admin is a basic CRUD system, it is not recommended to use in that way. Django views (your custom views) give you more power to control the process.

First of all, [Django Permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization) might be a good start point. Create Groups for user types and assign desired permissions for each group. Do not give permission for non-superusers to change group or permissions.

Second thing is using [Django Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/) to check data before saving it. For example, a `pre_save` signal for User creation can be used to check if `is_superuser`, `is_staff` values of the user are set by non-superuser. You can add [`added_by`](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/current_user.html) value to the user model and verify your checks using this value.

Also, using custom forms for Django admin is also possible and might be the simplest solution for it. Just make a custom form for creating and editing users and verify changes in the form directly before allowing the view to save anything. It is also possible to inform user that they don't have access for changes they made and also notify the management about the attempt.